# Find/Filter the lists with a specific key-value pair from a JSON ARRAY (list of maps)

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console, jenkins-groovy

I have a JSON array (list of maps) similar to:

```
def listOfMap = [[TESTCASE:1, METHOD:'CLICK', RESULT:'PASS'], 
      [TESTCASE:2, METHOD:'CLICK', RESULT:'FAIL'], 
      [TESTCASE:3, METHOD:'CLICK', RESULT:'FAIL'], 
      [TESTCASE:4, METHOD:'TYPETEXT', RESULT:'FAIL']]
```

1) I want to **get/filter/return** all the lists that contain the key-value pairs "**METHOD:CLICK**" and "**RESULT:FAIL**"

```
My output should return 2 lists out of 4: [TESTCASE:2, METHOD:CLICK, RESULT:FAIL], [TESTCASE:3, METHOD:CLICK, RESULT:FAIL]
```

2) I want to get the **count** of lists that contain the key-value pairs "**METHOD:CLICK**" and "**RESULT:FAIL**"

```
My output should be : 2
```

3) From the above list of maps, i want to get all the **unique/distinct values** for the key "**METHOD**"

```
My output should return unique values of the key method : CLICK, TYPETEXT
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Filtering

Groovy has a method called [`Collection.findAll(Closure closure)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)) that filters out all values that don't satisfy a predicate (expressed as a closure):

```
println listOfMap.findAll { map -> map.METHOD == 'CLICK' && map.RESULT == 'FAIL' }

// Output: [[TESTCASE:2, METHOD:CLICK, RESULT:FAIL], [TESTCASE:3, METHOD:CLICK, RESULT:FAIL]]
```

#### Counting

There is also a method [`DefaultGroovyMethods.count(Iterable<T> self, Closure closure)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#count-java.lang.Iterable-groovy.lang.Closure-) that expects a predicate and count how many elements satisfy it:

```
println listOfMap.count { map -> map.METHOD == 'CLICK' && map.RESULT == 'FAIL' }

// Output: 2
```

#### List of unique values from list of maps

For selecting a value for given key from a list of maps you can use [Groovy's spread operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator):

```
println listOfMap*.METHOD // btw, listOfMap.METHOD will do the same
```

This code translates to "for each element inside `listOfMap` get me a value for key `METHOD`. In the next step you can use [`Collection.unique()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#unique()) method to remove all duplicates:

```
println listOfMap*.METHOD.unique()

// Output: [CLICK, TYPETEXT]
```

**WARNING**: following method will not work in Jenkins pipeline Groovy script. In this case you will have to use [`Collection.collect(Closure closure)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collect(groovy.lang.Closure)) explicitly:

```
println listOfMap.collect { map -> map.METHOD }.unique()
```